# WP_Query reduces the number of results displayed per page

Tags: wordpress

I am encountering an issue lately. I am building a custom search function for wordpress and I am displaying the results based on a custom post type. Currently the number of results returned per page are reduced by 1 compared to the atual number (Eg. instead of 15 results per page wp_query returns 14). When I try to return all the results then it works fine but limiting the results per page has issues in retrieving the number of results.

Here is my array i passed.

```
array(
'post_type' => 'property',          
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'      =>  30,
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
)
```

Kindly offer me any solution to fix this.

Comment: I don't think it will solve the problem but you are passing post type 2 times.. You can remove the 'post_type' after 'post_status'

Comment: Sure. Done that and it is still the same. I have two different post types. The one one 'sold' displays results correctly but the one in question is not

Comment: query looks perfect, make sure alll of your posts are published (not draft) and try removing ignore_sticky_posts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support. I figured it out finally. The issue is with using the $query->the_post() at the wrong position after while loop. As I was using my custom pagination it filtered the index 0 on every page. I also set he offset to 0 just in case but works fine without passing offset as I have the ‘posts_per_page’ parameter acting on my pagination function.

Thanks again.